# Did Ronald Reagan have early onset dementia while president of the United States?

Tags: united-states, president, ronald-reagan

I recently read this great [article](https://www.nytimes.com/2015/03/31/health/parsing-ronald-reagans-words-for-early-signs-of-alzheimers.html?_r=0) about Reagan's change in speech pattern. It raised the question if he had early onset dementia while in office.

Comment: Possibly more suited to skeptics.SE?

Comment: Considering that the scientists in the article were unwilling to do more than speculate, I don't see how we could answer this better than "We don't know."  Any other answer is going to be opinion-based.

Comment: It's been theorized but, given he's dead, there's no way to confirm at this point.

Comment: @blip, re "*at this point*": we shouldn't rule out that some unknown future posthumous diagnostic method might provide adequate confirmation.

Comment: @Machavity You should add HTTPS if applicable to links in old posts when you bump them (I can't edit because it's only one character).

Answer (score 7):

[Early onset dementia](https://www.alz.org/alzheimers-dementia/what-is-alzheimers/younger-early-onset) is usually defined as affecting people younger than age 65.

Reagan was three weeks from his 70th birthday when taking office. Reagan died aged 93.

Therefore, it is highly unlikely he had early onset dementia.

Comment: I think the answer "he couldn't have had early onset dementia because at that age it would be called regular dementia" answers the question to the letter, but not to the intent.

Comment: I agree with @Philipp, so I downvoted the answer.  If your answer does not answer the _spirit_ of the question it is bad, even if it is technically correct.  Stack Exchange is about helping people learn.  It is not a trivia game.

Comment: @Philipp I think the reasoning is that if he lived until 93, it's unlikely that he'd had dementia while in office, let alone early-onset way before that. It's not impossible to live decades from the diagnosis, but it less common. See [*"General life expectancy for someone with Alzheimer's is around 8-12 years from diagnosis although this does depend on age and health. If you were relatively fit and healthy on diagnosis you could live considerably longer than this."*](https://www.unforgettable.org/blog/what-is-the-life-expectancy-for-someone-with-dementia/)

Answer (score 5):

Various articles make the claim, however the original statement that the articles are based on **seems to imply** that it is a matter of predicting the future onset of Alzheimer's based on subtle differences in speech.

[Parsing Ronald Reagan’s Words for Early Signs of Alzheimer’s](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/03/31/health/parsing-ronald-reagans-words-for-early-signs-of-alzheimers.html?_r=0)

The [findings](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25633673?dopt=Abstract), published in The Journal of Alzheimer’s Disease by researchers at Arizona State University, do not prove that Mr. Reagan exhibited signs of dementia that would have adversely affected his judgment and ability to make decisions in office.

But the research does suggest that alterations in speech one day might be used to predict development of Alzheimer’s and other neurological conditions years before symptoms are clinically perceptible.